# How do I use quotation marks in fstream?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, double-quotes

I want to output a line into a `.plt` file that says `"one-D Hydro"` with the double quotation marks and so far I have this problem.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        fstream gnuplot_file;        

        gnuplot_file.open ("sod.plt");
        gnuplot_file<<"set title"<< ""one-D Hydro""<<std::endl;
        gnuplot_file.close();
        system("gnuplot.exe sod.plt");


        return 0;
}
```

Line 11 will not allow it to compile because I can't seem to close the statement. The error is just as useless by the way.

`gnuplot_call.cpp|11|error: expected ';' before 'one'|`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C++03 (or even C) use backslashes to escapes double-quotes in string literals:

```
    gnuplot_file << "set title" << "\"one-D Hydro\"" << std::endl;
```

<sup>Notice that `gnuplot` may require you to also escape some characters, e.g. if you wanted the title to contain quotes!</sup>

With [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) you could use [raw string literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Raw_strings), e.g.

```
   gnuplot_file<< R"*(set title "one-D Hydro")*" << std::endl;
```

BTW, you could be interested by [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) and `pclose`, if your operating system and C++ library provides them. You would just `popen` the `gnuplot` process and send commands to it, finally `pclose`-ing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to include escape character [i.e.,back slash] in the code where you are trying to add double quotes. 
For example:

```
"\"one-D Hydro\""
```

btw why are you using `std::` once you have defined namespace for it you can directly use endl.